# Impactjs - image totatly crashed

Tags: google-chrome, html5-canvas, impactjs

I'm currently developing my first game in impactjs ( canvas & html5 ), user just send me this picture, it seems that one of the pictures shows really bad :-)

Is this a canvas specific problem/ or just webbrowser specific ( tested on chrome ) ?

Any ideas ? :)

[image: problematic image]

Comment: We can only guess as we need to see the code causing the problem. Could you try to reproduce the problem for us (fiddle).

Comment: Well, that is the problem, that it happened only once on client web-browser :) I think that this might be some browser issue, but I want to be 100% sure :)

Comment: I've noticed something similar to this when I worked directly with the context but it was bug in the code. And not browser specific.